# get_page_template returning nothing

Tags: theme-development, page-template, code

I run this code in

`front-page.php`

as well in

`category-foo.php`

```
<?php echo is_page_template( 'front-page.php' ) ? "yes" : "no" ?>
```

and get both times "no" printed

i tried as well

```
<?php echo get_page_template() ?>
```

returning nothing.

I as well tried

```
  <?php echo get_category_template() ?>
```

What I want to know, is in which main template file I am.
E.g.

I want to call from `header.php`

```
<?php if ( currFilename(__FILE__) != "front-page" ) : ?>
    <div>Fancy slogan</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

which obviously does not work this way.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [`is_front_page()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)? It should do what you're looking to do.

Unless you've set up front-page.php with the Page Template commented header syntax that identifies the file is a Page Template, I don't think you can use the `is_page_template()` or `get_page_template()` functions.

As for the category page, if you are loading category-foo.php, then aren't you already aware of what category template you are on and therefore do not need a conditional? Maybe I don't understand the context of the second part to the question.

Comment: well, you are ONLY aware in the category template. You are not aware in the header where you are. And if I understand correctly, there is, sadly, no way to set a variable in category-foo.php that can be read in the header in plain php.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. I think what you want then is [`is_category`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category).